# How to solve at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:832)

Tags: android

I am using the Slidemenu Library and i get the error  Please told me how to solve this error

```
enter code here

09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:1387)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:370)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4194)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:832)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2049)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1429)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1172)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1749)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 11:18:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(26322):    at java.
```

Answer (score 3):

I've never used this library but it seems that your menu is making your view hierarchy too deep (too many nested layers). Use Hierarchy Viewer to examine the depth of the tree, you shouldn't exceed 10-12 layers.

Comment: Hi! I have exactly the same problems. It is happen using the jeremy feinstein sliding menu in old devices. Exactly, it is broken using a Android 2.3.3 version. How did you fix this problem?

Comment: You're asking the wrong person :) that said, these sorts of problems happen when the view tree is too deep, remove a few layers of nesting (e.g. by combining nested layouts into a single one or by writing custom views) and it will fix itself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your code that generates your fragments, you are probably creating several times the same fragments. You can try two options:

1. Don't recreate your fragments if they are already `!= null`. You can add a simples code to check this and ignore the creation step.
2. Maybe you need your fragments alive, and must not recreate then, you can use this method `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag` to get a already created fragment.